# Performance measurement in distributed system (Java + C#)

Tags: java, c#, performance, time

I have a distributed system with a server that is written in Java and a Client that is written in C#. I want to do some performance measurements on that system, e.g. "How long does one roundtrip take?" or "What is the time between sending the request and calculating the response value?".

My first attempt was to print timestamps at specific situations on server and client and later calculate the differences between the two timestamps to get the duration.

BUT... when I ran the test, I noticed that sometimes the difference between two timestamps (A-B) was negative, even though timestamp B was created before timestamp A. (one of the timestamps was created on the server, the other one on the client) So I guess that the way the timestamps are created is not a exactly the same.

Does anybody have an idea how I can do that correctly?

I hope that I could explain my problem. If there are any questions, please let me know in the comments.

**EDIT: further information about the setup**

The C#-client is running on my local PC. The Java-server is running on a virtual machine, which itself is located on my PC.

Comment: Are you creating both timestamps on the same system?

Comment: I updated the question with the answer.

Comment: It's possible that your local PC and your virtual machine don't have exactly matching local times - timestamps are usually created using the machine's local time.

Comment: @UnholySheep: both machines are synchronized with the same time server